# Can 'is/are named' be a passive construction?

Tags: passive-voice

When you use the verb *name* denoting "give a name to", it certainly can be used in a passive construction, as in:

> Taylor Swift has countless Grammys and American Music Awards, but this new honor will be a first for the global pop star.
>
> *A newly discovered species of millipede was **named** after Swift*, according to a study published in the journal ZooKeys. It’s called Nannaria swiftae, or Swift twisted-claw millipede.
>
> Lead study author Derek Hennen is a self-proclaimed Swiftie and wanted to honor the singer.

([CNN, 2022](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/04/20/us/taylor-swift-millipede-new-species-scn/index.html))

The italicized passive clause corresponds to this active clause:

> *An entomologist named a newly discovered species of millipede after Swift*

Both the passive and active clauses denote the past action of naming the new species after the singer. That is, they mean the same thing.

Now, what if we use *is* instead of *was* in the passive clause?

> *A newly discovered species of millipede is named after Swift*

Is it still a passive clause? Does it correspond to this active clause?

> ?*An entomologist names a newly discovered species of millipede after Swift*

I don't think so. In fact, I can't think of an example where *is/are named*, unlike *was/were named*, can be passive.

Interestingly, though, *is/are/was/were called* is always passive, regardless of the form of the verb *be*. For example, the clause in the next sentence above (*It’s called Nannaria swiftae*) does correspond to an active clause:

> *He calls it Nannaria swiftae*

Is there any logical way to explain all this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for. Is this about use of the present passive, or about the role of the word "named" or what? Do you want a sentence like "This picture shows the moment when a newly discovered species of millipede is named after Swift by anthropologist Jane Smith" which seems to include a passive? If so, why?

Comment: Passive, no problem: *Newly discovered species are named every day.* From: *Entomologists name newly discovered species every day.*

Comment: @StuartF It's about a little bit of both, but more about the word "named", especially when it is compared with "called". At least for now.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Right. But I think your example adds just another interesting layer of complication to the already complex question.

Comment: Some past participles can act adjectivally. **Active**: *Entomologists named the species Nannaria swiftae.* **Passive**: *The species was named Nannaria swiftae by entomologists.* **Adjectival**: *Now the species is named. It's a named species.* Others can't. **Active**: *Entomologists called the species Nannaria swiftae.* **Passive**: *The species was called Nannaria swiftae by entomologists.* **Not adjectival:** *\*Now the species is called. It's a called species.* You could look at *elected* vs. *voted* the same way.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Good examples! I would add these, though. **Passive:** _The species is named Nannaria swiftae by entomologists._ (which works only in some special contexts) **Adjectival:** _The species is named Nannaria swiftae._ **Passive:** _The species is called Nannaria swiftae (by entomologists)._ Note here that it's passive with or without _by entomologists_. So the question is why _name_ and _call_, which are synonymous, behave differently in these constructions.

Comment: That would be your new question! To focus, though, I would suggest you get rid of this: "which works only in some special contexts." There is nothing special or particularly unusual about *is named* in the passive voice.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I don't think it's a new question. I've already compared the verbs at the end of the question. In fact, I've intentionally selected this particular article for that reason.

Comment: Look at your question title.

Answer (score 0):

> *A newly discovered species of millipede was **named** after Swift*, corresponds to this active clause: *An entomologist named a newly discovered species of millipede after Swift*

In fact, the passive is >*A newly discovered species of millipede was **named** after Swift **by an anthropologist.***

> Now, what if we use *is* instead of *was* in the passive clause?
>
> *A newly discovered species of millipede is named after Swift*

Which, **depending on context**, is either

(i) a passive and the same as *A newly discovered species of millipede is **named** after Swift **by an anthropologist***

(ii)    comparable to *A newly discovered species of millipede is **big***

In (i) ***is*** is a lexically empty auxiliary signalling the passive.

In (ii) ***is*** is a lexically empty copula followed by a complement.

Comment: In what context, can you say (i) as passive? In other words, in what context, can you say _An entomologist names a newly discovered species of millipede after Swift_?

Comment: Your example is a valid sentence and would make a good headline. Also "Let's say that an entomologist names a newly discovered species of millipede after Swift - how would this be seen in the scientific world?"

Comment: You may be right, but I think you know I'm not looking for some rare cases in which 'is/are named' can be used as passive. Please try to "answer" the question, rather than find fault with it.

Comment: >JK2 I am afraid I don't understand your objection. I have not given you a rare case. It is a case that demonstrates a correct use.

Comment: "Rare" does not mean "incorrect". In fact, I said you're right. It's just that I didn't ask for a correct case where "is/are named" can be legitimately passive. Your post can be a good comment, just as Tinfoil Hat's is, but I don't think it can be an "answer".

Comment: @JK2 You read the last two lines?

Comment: Of course I did. But I'm not just asking about "adjectival passives" (as opposed to "verbal passives"), which I'm pretty familiar with. What I'm asking is what's so special about such verbs as "name" that they trigger "adjectival passives" much more easily than such verbs as "call". Maybe I should edit the question to clarify this point.

Comment: @JK2 *Maybe I should edit the question to clarify this point.* - Good call.